# Linux UDP socket: select() is not notified?

Tags: linux, sockets, udp

I have Linux `UDP` socket code like this:

```
//create the UDP socket and bind to a local port 5001
//sockfd = socket(AF_INET, UDP, 0);
//bind(sockfd, .., ...);
recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, &addrlen);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

to here, `recvfrom` works fine, and `printf` above can prints what I send from `ncat` client.

But if I put `recvfrom` after `select()`, see code below, `select()` will not return, when I send data from `ncat` client to this socket.

```
max_fd = 0
FD_ZERO(&read_set);
FD_SET(sockfd, &read_set);

while (1) {
    i = select(max_fd + 1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);  //==> !!! select() is not returned from ncat sent data to this socket
    if (i < 0 && errno != EINTR) { 
         .............
    }
    for (current_fd = 0; current_fd <= max_fd; current_fd++){
        if ( !FD_ISSET(current_fd, &read_set) )
                continue;
         nbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, &addrlen);
         printf("%d bytes received \n", nbytes );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this `C` or `C++`, I'm thinking `C` but I'd rather not assume.

Comment: You need to restore the read_ste every time around the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (1) {
 FD_ZERO(&read_set);
 FD_SET(sockfd, &read_set);
 i = select(max_fd + 1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);  
if (i < 0 && errno != EINTR) { 
     .............
}
for (current_fd = 0; current_fd <= max_fd; current_fd++){
    if ( !FD_ISSET(current_fd, &read_set) )
            continue;
     nbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr    *)&remote_addr, &addrlen);
     printf("%d bytes received \n", nbytes );
}
}
```